# React Hooks JS Lint warning useEffect has a missing dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am looking at the documentation from react regarding [omitting functions from the list of dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)  because I got this error in my js linter. I have tried to amend my code like the docs show, but I feel like I am missing something, because I still get the same error. I will post my code before and after my attempt. Thanks.

```
warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleDocumentScrollThrottled'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Code Before attempted fix

```
/* Completed useDocumentScrollThrottled utility function */

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { throttle } from 'lodash';

function useDocumentScrollThrottled(callback) {
  const [, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  let previousScrollTop = 200;

  function handleDocumentScroll() {
    const { scrollTop: currentScrollTop } = document.documentElement || document.body;

    setScrollPosition(previousPosition => {
      previousScrollTop = previousPosition;
      return currentScrollTop;
    });

    callback({ previousScrollTop, currentScrollTop });
  }

  const handleDocumentScrollThrottled = throttle(handleDocumentScroll, 250);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleDocumentScrollThrottled);

    return () =>
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleDocumentScrollThrottled);
  }, []);
}

export default useDocumentScrollThrottled;
```

Code after attempted fix

```
...

useEffect(() => {

    function doSomething(){
      window.addEventListener('scroll', handleDocumentScrollThrottled);

    return () =>
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleDocumentScrollThrottled);
    } 

    doSomething();

  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error will not get resolved, just because you are wrapping the dependency inside another function. The way that's suggested in the docs with the `doSomething` exmaple is to move the function out of your hook's scope. This is not possible in your case as your `handleDocumentScroll` depends on a setter that's only available in the hook.

**Instead you have to:**

Add the dependency of `handleDocumentScrollThrottled` to your dependency array like so:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //...
  }, [handleDocumentScrollThrottled]);
```

This of course will not work, as `handleDocumentScrollThrottled` is reallocated with every render, therefore causing this effect to trigger every single time. That's very likely not what you wanted.

The solution here is to *use a memoized* value for handleDocumentScrollThrottled, so that it does not change on every re-render:

```
  const handleDocumentScrollThrottled = useMemo(() => {
    function handleDocumentScroll() {
      const { scrollTop: currentScrollTop } = document.documentElement || document.body;

      setScrollPosition(previousPosition => {
        previousScrollTop = previousPosition;
        return currentScrollTop;
      });

      callback({ previousScrollTop, currentScrollTop });
    }

    return throttle(handleDocumentScroll, 250);
  }, []);
```

However, I want to note that (ab)using a setter to set another variable is super hacky and you should probably use a `ref` to track your old scroll position instead.

Comment: Does this look like a better way to track scroll position using ref? https://dev.to/n8tb1t/tracking-scroll-position-with-react-hooks-3bbj

Comment: @AndersKitson Yes, this is what I meant. Using the ref allows you to instantly access the set value (when you're using a state setter this is not available, until the next render, which in your case is too late), but without introducing possible side effects.